# Rich text box formatting in code

Tags: c#, debugging

I am using the code given [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0dhsw8eb) and I changed it to format the text in a rich text box as follows:

```
private void richTextBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        richTextBox1.Rtf = @"{\rtf1\ansi " + richTextBox1.Text;
    }
```

It works normally and formats the code when I leave, but there are two things wrong:

1. There's no space between the formatted words and the none formatted words after

> Hey look, \b I'm bold\b and I'm not

comes out as:

> Hey look, **I'm bold** and I'm not

2. When I click on the text box again to edit it, all the formatting goes away.

Answer (score 0):

Try "Hey look, \b I'm bold \b0 and I'm not" (note the extra spacing) to fix the first issue.

If the control characters are being lost, you might be accessing the text content the wrong way. Use the `Rtf` property of the RichTextBox object instead of the `Text` property.

Comment: That makes sense lol, thank you, and it doesn't come back, that's the problem, sorry I should have specified that.

Comment: Are you accessing the text in the box using the `Rtf` property or the `Text` property? `Text` will cause you to lose the formatting characters but `Rtf` will keep them.

Comment: I was thinking about that, but when I do that, it doesn't format at all, due to the fact that there isn't any formatting yet, it's just text.

Comment: Change `richTextBox1.Rtf = @"{\rtf1\ansi " + richTextBox1.Text;` to `richTextBox1.Rtf = @"{\rtf1\ansi " + richTextBox1.Rtf;` is what I mean. You've tried that?

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that, and when I click out of the text box, it keeps the \b and doesn't format it.

Comment: Oh, what you want is probably the opposite of what you've done then, `richTextBox1.Text = @"{\rtf1\ansi " + richTextBox1.Rtf;` (it should render the formatting characters but not lose them this way)

Comment: Lol I kinda figured something like this would happen, but no it comes up as:

{\rtf1\ansi {\rtf1\ansi\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Calibri;}}
\viewkind4\uc1\pard\lang1033\f0\fs30 Hey look, \\b I'm bold \\b0 and I'm not\par
}

Answer (score 0):

As Peter G told me and I missed entirely, the answer to the first problem was a missing space.  In the second problem, what I did was made a string, before it formats the code, it saves the text box's text into the string (Hey look, \b I'm bold \b0 and I'm not), then it formats the code.  Then I have it set to set the text box's text to be that string.

```
string text1;

private void richTextBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        text1 = richTextBox1.Text;
        richTextBox1.Rtf = @"{\rtf1\ansi " + richTextBox1.Text;
    }

    private void richTextBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        richTextBox1.Text = text1;
    }
```